# Chicken characteristics

Tags: chicken

How would you describe the texture, smell & taste of chicken. Im doing a hospitality course at tafe and i'm finding it difficult to find the write description, any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

When cooked correctly, the texture of chicken is tender and juicy. When overcooked, chicken becomes dry and stringy.

The regular chicken you get at the supermarket doesn't have any distinctive smell or taste by itself, and it really depends on what you add to flavor the chicken.